# WSO2 - Identity Server - Sending SMS on self user registration by API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am calling /api/identity/user/v1.0/me API of WSO2 identity server 6.1.0 in order to self register a user, i added:

{
"uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/identity/preferredChannel",
"value": "SMS"
}

to the body claims. I also added SMS to Manage Self-Sign-Up purposes  under user onboarding > self registration service provider resident configuration. In addition, User self registration    is checked and Lock user account on creation    is checked as well. By it is still attempting to send an email on user creation. What else should i change in order to get a verification code by SMS?

Under deployment.toml i have the following:

```
#[identity_mgt.user_self_registration]
default_notification_channel = "SMS"
enable_resolve_notification_channel = true


[identity_mgt.user_self_registration]
allow_self_registration=true
lock_on_creation=true
enable_recaptcha=true
verification_email_validity="1440"
callback_url="[${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}].*    [/authenticationendpoint/login.do]*"
enable_resend_confirmation_recaptcha=true

[identity_mgt.user_self_registration.notification]
manage_internally=true
```

Comment: have you commented `#[identity_mgt.user_self_registration]` in the deployment.toml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the following config

```
#[identity_mgt.user_self_registration]
default_notification_channel = "SMS"
enable_resolve_notification_channel = true
```

Those should be corrected as follows:

```
[identity_mgt.notification]
default_notification_channel = "SMS"
resolve_notification_channel = true
```

`enable_resolve_notification_channel` should be renamed as `resolve_notification_channel`.
And the header property inside the square brackets should be `[identity_mgt.notification]`

Follow https://medium.com/p/fb59e6465631 this article for more details

Comment: Thank you i got this as response: {
    "code": "USR-02001",
    "message": "Successful user self registration. Pending account verification.",
    "notificationChannel": "SMS"
}  but the sms was not received and in the wso2carbon.log we have no errors. Is there any config file where we can check the sms issues? thank you in advance for your help

Comment: i forgot to say that my IS is version 6.1.0

Comment: What is the SMS provider that you use? Did you update the `SMSPublisher.xml` file properly? As a mock could you please check with a webhook as mentioned in https://medium.com/p/fb59e6465631

Comment: nexmo:
        <inline>{"api_key"="thekey",
            "api_secret"="thesecret",
            "from"="NEXMO",
            "to"={{mobile}},
            "text"={{body}}
            }</inline>
    </mapping>

Comment: If your SMS provider is Vonage(Nexmo)n, the data inside the <inline> tag should be changed as follows (Instead of = , use : )

<inline>{
"api_key":"12**33",
"api_secret":"F**a",
"from":"NEXMO",
"to":{{mobile}},
"text":{{body}}
}</inline>

Comment: Is it possible to do resend-code using apis? i know we have one for account recovery but is there any for the self registration? (email and/or sms)

Comment: Try this https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/use-the-self-sign-up-rest-apis/#/Self%20Register/post_resend_code resend code API